# Which version of JSON Schema is Visual Studio Code using

Tags: visual-studio-code

The documentation (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/json) does not say specific version.  I know that VSCode supports draft-04 for sure as I am using it, but I wonder if it supports draft-06 too.

Comment: Asking this as an issue on the VS Code Github would be a better bet for getting a response. The devs working on the project will know more about it than any of us here can possibly know.

Comment: I thought about that too, but in https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/new, they suggest I ask the question here.   Anyway, I'll file an issue there and hope they can answer.

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/34590